# Cross Product answer isn't correct?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm having an issue with doing a function that takes 2 inputs: R (unit vector) and v (vector) and outputs a list of 3 vectors {vr,vp,vc}

```
vr = (v.R)R          
vp = v-vr           
vc = R*vp

R = {0.36,0.48,0.8}
v can equal i{1,0,0},j{0,1,0},k{0,0,1}
```

My issue is that with vc, it will give the incorrect answer at the position of the 1 in the v

````
  ``` 
   rotPrep[R_,v_]:= {Dot[v,R]R, v - Dot[v,R]R, Cross[R, v - Dot[v,R]R]};

   Print["{ir,ip,ic} = ", rotPrep[R,i]];

   Print["{jr,jp,jc} = ", rotPrep[R,j]];

   Print["{kr,kp,kc} = ", rotPrep[R,k]];

  ```
````

I seem to have i right, but j and k gives me 1.9984x10^-17 in the position 1 was in.

```
   {ir,ip,ic} = {{0.1296,0.1728,0.288},{0.8704,-0.1728,-0.288},{0,0.8,-0.48}} 
   {jr,jp,jc} = {{0.1728,0.2304,0.384},{-0.1728,0.7696,-0.384},{-0.8,1.9984x10^-17,0.36}} 
   {kr,kp,kc} = {{0.288,0.384,0.64},{-0.288,-0.384,0.36},{0.48,-0.36,-1.9984x10^-17}}
```

Comment: I have tried to scrape-n-paste-and-run your code and can't reproduce what you are seeing. I am ASSUMING your problem is because you are subtracting two approximate decimal values and the result is almost, but not exactly, zero. Thus you are seeing floating point noise. Try to incorporate the following idea and see if it fixes your problem `R = Rationalize[{0.36,0.48,0.8}];
rotPrep[R_,v_]:=N[{Dot[v,R]R, v - Dot[v,R]R, Cross[R, v - Dot[v,R]R]}];` which uses `Rationalize` and `N` to try to get exact zeros instead of approximate zeros.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill said in the comments, this is the correct way of writing it

```
R = Rationalize[{0.36,0.48,0.8}]; 
rotPrep[R_,v_]:=N[{Dot[v,R]R, v - Dot[v,R]R, Cross[R, v - Dot[v,R]R]}];
```